# Google maps beam to show user directions/heading in iOS GMSMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, gmsmapview

Is it possible to use a shining blue beam instead inconspicuous arrow in iOS **GMSMapView**? This new feature is available for Google Maps on Android. Anyone experimented or tried this new feature in iOS? Kindly share your thoughts please.

Thanks!

[image: shining blue beam]